# Generated C# LINQ to SQL Classes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq-to-sql

Visual Studio will generate the codes itself in DataClasses.designer.cs after I drag a table from the Server Explorer to DataClasses.dbml.

If the table's name end with a 's', such as `Books`, VS will remove the 's' In the class name and keep the 's' with the property name:

```
public System.Data.Linq.Table<Book> Books
{
    get
    {
        return this.GetTable<Book>();
    }
}
```

If the table does not end with a 's', such as `Book`, VS will keep the class name and add a 's' to the property name:

```
public System.Data.Linq.Table<Book> Books
{
    get
    {
        return this.GetTable<Book>();
    }
}
```

However, my colleague's VS just keeps the names:

```
Book: public System.Data.Linq.Table<Book> Book
Books: public System.Data.Linq.Table<Books> Books
```

We work on a same project with our own pc. If drag a new table to DataClasses.dbml and save, my VS will change the his old codes:

```
public System.Data.Linq.Table<Book> Book
```

to

```
public System.Data.Linq.Table<Book> Books
```

and all his codes such as

```
DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext();
var book = db.Book;
```

will be error, because now it must be:

```
var book = db.Books;
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Look here (and around): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.conventions.pluralizingtablenameconvention(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Export .vssettings and make your colleague use them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, when you drag database objects that have names ending in s or ies from Server Explorer/Database Explorer onto the LINQ to SQL Tools in Visual Studio, the names of the generated entity classes are changed from plural to singular. This is done to more accurately represent the fact that the instantiated entity class maps to a single record of data. For example, adding a Customers table to the O/R Designer results in an entity class named Customer because the class will hold data for only a single customer.

How to: Turn pluralization on and off (O/R Designer):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384507.aspx